# vscode disable variable view in debugging

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Can I somehow disable the variable view in the debugging mode in vscode?
Many of my objects are complex and large, and calling the `repr()` function for each variable takes a lot of time. As I do not use the window, I wonder whether I can simply not use the variable window.

[image]

Comment: Just right-click on  The `Variables` header and choose `Hide 'Variables'`.

Comment: That is embarrassing:) Worked. I would've never guessed that hiding it would save me from the __repr__ computation. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Right click variables
2. Click any one in the red box

[image]